# chaining commands with ecs-exec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

We are using ecs-exec to connect containers running in AWS. I need to chain two commands so they can run one after another. These commands are

1. rake db:migrate
2. exec $SHELL

I am doing the chaining like `rake db:migrate ; exec $SHELL` . The reason is we want to keep the shell open after running db:migrate. When I run this above chained command inside the container then it works as expected. But when I run it at the time of connecting to container using ecs-exec  then it shows below error

> Don't know how to build task ';' (See the list of available tasks with
> `rake --tasks`) /usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in
> `<top (required)>' (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Looks like it is taking ; exec $SHELL as an argument for rake db:migrate command. My only goal is to first run rake db:migrate and then keep the shell open. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I don't want to answer because I don't know ecs-exec specifically, but one trick for running multiple commands for things that otherwise accept one is using `sh -c 'command1; command2'`

Comment: @jordanm can you explain a bit more about this approach? I already tried to use this, mentioned on ticket as well. But it didnt work.

Comment: If you are building these images already, which I assume you are in order to include your Ruby code, why not just include a shell script that runs your 2 commands. Then you could run that shell script via ECS Exec.

Comment: @MarkB this will be extra work. I agree thats one way. but first this will create an extra dependency and second we will have to update all docker images which is about 50+ (Microservices)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do this.

```
bash -c "rake db:migrate && $SHELL"
```